# Python Blockchain Module get_block_height Function

Tags: python, blockchain, bitcoin

I am very new to this blockchain module and I cannot seem to find much proper tutorials online.

from blockchain import blockexplorer as be
be.get_block_height()

May I ask what does this output of the function give me? From what I understand we pass in the height (or the number position of a particular block in a blockchain) into the function and it should return to you a block object or something. I checked the documentation it said it returns an array of blocks? How does that work because we are passing a specific height into the function such as the 5000th block, so how does the output return to you more than 1 block instead?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blockchain is a list of blocks. As new transactions are created, a block will fill up and a new block is created. The chain height is the chain length; the number of blocks in the chain. It's a good way of determining if a blockchain node is up to date with the latest transactions.

`be.get_block_height()` returns an array of blocks at the specified height (from whatever node you're connected to).

The reason it can have multiple blocks at the same height is due to the mining process. When a block is filled, miners validate the the block and add it to the chain. If multiple miners, the first to validate the block wins. In the case of a tie, the chain temporarily forks so there are multiple blocks at the same height. One of the forks will eventually be dropped (orphaned) and the main chain will continue with the other fork.

Here is an article on blockchain height:
https://hedgetrade.com/what-is-block-height

Check this explorer. You can see the current height of the bitcoin blockchain
https://www.blockchain.com/explorer

Comment: Thank you for the insight but hm.. I think the output of this function does not give you the height but the block object itself.

Comment: You are correct, I made an assumption based on the function name. I reviewed the source code and updated the answer. Thanks for catching this.

Comment: Thank you very much, this makes more sense ! I was wondering how can there be multiple blocks having the same height when the height specifically indicates the number position that block is in, in the entire blockchain. I will be asking another question regarding extracting the data from blockchain.com so do help me take a look too bud thanks !